# Show all ways 365 can be written as the sum of 2 or more different perfect square numbers?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I need help with this problem please explain all the appropriate steps.

Comment: Are the perfect square numbers assumed to be *pairwise* distinct?

Answer (score 4):

[This program](https://tio.run/##bY5BDoIwEEX3nOKvzAwxRiCaSICLGBckFC0phbRl4elr27DQxOXM/PffrG/3WnTlvUILJa0j0@unoOJYnpmzzAgbDlY4CsO4GEhIjT2DpkGI1RkgR5DdZiKS6DpMjAMKzkndp0eel4zITl/sjRlti@p6STwQTKd@GMhtqxKJ@8Mkz48ilhS8PyeUmFNe2Fi6GqkdxSV7/wE) gives you all of the results.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive program seems a reasonable approach.  Write a routine that takes the target number which starts at $365$ here and a maximum square to use.  If you don't supply it, it could compute the maximum, which here is $19$.  It would try using $19$, compute $365-19^2=4$ and call itself to express $4$.  When it ran out of ways to express $4$ it returns and the first instance tries to express $365$ with a maximum of $18^2$ and so on.  You could save some time by caching the results for small numbers.

Comment: or `forsubset(19,s,if(norml2(Vec(s))==365,print(s)))`

Answer (score 0):

- parity considerations show an odd number of them are odd.
- mod 3, a 2 mod 3 number of them are 1 mod 3

looking at these mod 6

- the number of 1,4 mod 6 is either 2 or 5 mod 6
- the number of 1,3 mod 6 is in 1,3,5 mod 6

we also have

- the number of 1 mod 6 is 2 mod 3  in 1,3 only scenario
- the number of 1 mod 6 is 1 mod 3 in 1,4 only scenario.
- the number of 1 mod 6 is 5 mod 6 in the 1 only scenario
- the only 3 or only 4 scenarios can't work.
- the number of 4 mod 6 is 2 mod 3 in the 3,4 only scenario
- the number of 1,4 mod 6 is 2 mod 3 in the 1,3,4 scenario.

Finally we have that at least one of the squares stays below 182, leading to one of the bases being below 14.

Comment: It says unique squares...

Comment: sorry I'll leave that part out then.